# Python script to generate set of random numbers with a constraint

Tags: python-3.x, data-manipulation, data-generation

I'd like the script to output 159 random numbers between "0.04" and "4.5" that have a total that matches the target total. Here is what I have so far, but this only generates 142 numbers. How can I enforce it to create 159 numbers?

```
import random

target_total = 298.51
total_numbers = 159
min_value = 0.04
max_value = 4.50

random_numbers = []

for i in range(total_numbers - 1):
    # Generate a random number within the specified range
    num = round(random.uniform(min_value, max_value), 2)  # Limit to 2 decimal places
    
    # Append the number to the list
    random_numbers.append(num)
    
    # Calculate the current sum of numbers
    current_sum = round(sum(random_numbers), 2)
    
    # If the current sum exceeds the target total, remove the last number
    while current_sum > target_total:
        excess = current_sum - target_total
        random_numbers.remove(random_numbers[-1])
        current_sum = round(current_sum - excess, 2)

# The last number is adjusted to reach the target total
last_num = round(target_total - sum(random_numbers), 2)
random_numbers.append(last_num)

# Print each generated number with row numbers on a new line
for i, num in enumerate(random_numbers, start=1):
    print(f"Row {i}: {num}")

print("Total sum:", round(sum(random_numbers), 2))
```

Comment: What you ask for isn't possible, at the very least the final number won't be random.

Comment: @MarkRansom - I'm curious to understand why? This seems like quite a simple challenge on face value, but I am starting to see its quite the problem. Any further insights would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens after you've chosen 158 numbers?  How random do you think the 159th will be?

Comment: I see what you mean now you put it like that. Thanks for the repsonse.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here is: Though the max_value is 4.50, if more numbers of random numbers created is near the maximum value, To achieve the target total will be reached with lesser numbers of total numbers. Also, The loop will continue to endless numbers if we use this method. So we have to decide the max_value ourselves. Here I have given a better method. And explanation is given inside:

```
import random as rd
target_total = 298.51
total_numbers = 159
each_number = target_total/total_numbers

#calculate the sum of adjacent two numbers
adj_sum = each_number*2

min_value = 0.04
random_numbers = []

#create a loop for 1 number less than the total numbers i.e 158. 
# We will find out the last number afterwards
for i in range(total_numbers-1):
    #generate random number only for even index
    if i%2==0:
        #generate random_number between min_value and the adj_sum
        
        number = rd.uniform(min_value, adj_sum)
    #if i is odd the random number should be the difference between adj_sum and previous number
    else:
        number = adj_sum - number
    
    #round_off to 2 decimals and append
    random_numbers.append(round(number,2))

#find the last number

sum = round(sum(random_numbers), 2)
last_number = round((target_total - sum),2)

#append the last number
random_numbers.append(last_number)

sum = sum + last_number

for i, num in enumerate(random_numbers, start=1):
    print(f"Row {i}: {num}")

print("Total sum:", round(sum, 2))
```

If you want every random number should be unique at any cost, you can add a while loop after the line 18. i.e I've included the line after which you should insert the following code

```
#generate random_number between min_value and the adj_sum(line 17)
    number = rd.uniform(min_value, adj_sum) #line 18
    j = 0
    while j>=0:
        if number not in random_numbers:
            break
        else:
            j += 1
```